# Lua issue with table length?

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I was messing around with Lua tables and I noticed:

```
local t1 = {1, 5, nil, 10}
local t2 = {1, 5, nil, 10, nil}

print(t1[5], t2[5]) --> nil   nil
print(#t1, #t2) --> 4   2
```

I was expecting the length of both tables to be 4, but the length of `t2` turned out to be 2.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It's just easier to call `#` the _sequence length operator_ and `ipairs` the _sequence iterator._ Neither of your tables have a sequence. (It seems to be an unstated requirement that `#` return a non-negative integer even when invoked on a table without a sequence.) All of these behaviors enable time and space optimizations for sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Frequently, in Lua, we assume that an array ends just before its first nil element. This convention has one drawback: We cannot have a nil inside an array. [...] But sometimes we must allow nils inside an array. In such cases, we need a method to keep an explicit size for an array.

From [Programming in Lua 19.1](http://www.lua.org/pil/19.1.html).